# How to cross compile debian package for ARM Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I use arm-bcm2708 toolchain for cross compiler.

Now I want to build debian package.

> ```
> $ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc
> ```

I got error

> ```
> ... (ELF format: 'elf32-littlearm'; RPATH: '')
> dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot continue due to the error above
> Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
> To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
> ```

I don't want to build it on the pi. So how to cross-compile a RPi debian package on PC?

Answer (score 5):

The first method were to use the same host Debian distribution as Raspberry Pi Debian. For example 7.0. Add `deb http://www.emdebian.org/debian/ unstable main`
to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and install the toolchain:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install emdebian-archive-keyring
apt-get install gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf
apt-get install build-essential git debootstrap u-boot-tools
```

Via [xapt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/xapt.1.html) you can then install cross-compiled dependencies. Perhaps you'll be able to use `dpkg-buildpackage` then.

**Alternative:**

You can convert your package to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html) and use [CPack](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackPackageGenerators) to generate a deb file. This approach will work on other distributions like openSuSe, Fedora too.

**Update:**

As Emdebian distributions updates have ceased, it is recommended to switch to newer Debian versions and make use of [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch) feature.

Comment: "As of July 2014, updates to the Emdebian distributions ceased. There will be no further updates and no further stable releases."